# Laravel 5: forget cache not working

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5

I try to delete specific cached data using:

```
Cache::forget('key');
```

also tried

```
Cache::pull('key');
```

but cache still existed in DB

note: I'm using Database cache, and Laravel 5.1.7

Comment: Are you sure the key is in your cache? Check by using `Cache::has('key')`

Comment: yes, I'm sure => I copy key from DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, the problem happen because I copy `cache` key from DB with `prefix`, and Laravel normally add another `prefix`, and it will never matched

Comment: Can you please elaborate this statement please?

Comment: How did you fix this?

Answer (score 3):

For the records: if you are using [cache tags](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache#cache-tags), the `forget` method will not work. This is what I managed to do to solve the problem:

```
    $cache_key = "MY_CACHE_KEY";
    $cache_tags = ["MY_CACHE_TAG"]; //SOMETIMES I USE MULTIPLE TAGS
    if (\Cache::tags($cache_tags)->has($cache_key)) {
        \Cache::tags($cache_tags)->forget($cache_key);
        $results = "CACHE item " . $cache_key . " forgotten";
    } else {
        $results = "Key " . $cache_key . " IS NOT CACHED";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone needs it, my problem was because of file permissions. So, you can try this command in the root of the project `chmod -R 755 .`. However, I did `chmod -R 777 .`, but that's not recommended.

Comment: Thanks, it solves the problem. It even not showing me any error in tinker CLI.